# Where to ask practical question on tiling

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> Is it possible to tile 3*2.4 rectangle with 4 convex polygons each cut from 1.2*2.4 rectangle?

[I tried on Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252898/is-it-possible-to-tile-32-4-rectangle-with-4-convex-polygons-each-cut-from-1-2), but it was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

If this is an applied, physical problem, DIY might be your best bet — but if this is simply a practical math problem, you might be on the right track.

**It doesn't sound like your question was off topic.** According to the close notice, they simply wanted you to provide additional context like how you might approach the problem and how you tried (and failed) to solve it yourself. In other words, **Math SE does not like *"do my work for me"* questions.**

It looks like you edited the question after closure to add some of the context they were looking for (including a partial solution you came up with yourself). My only suggestion is to change "is there a tool/method to devise a cutting plan" to *"How can I calculate this…?"* That will make it clear(er) that this is a math problem and not a DIY/Home Improvement issue.

The rest is about convincing the community you've put in the due diligence to get the question reopened. If simply editing the post does not accomplish that, there are a few ways you can escalate the issue as appropriate:

1. Add a comment to explain how you addressed their concerns (and dilligently respond to any feedback or request for clarification that may follow).
2. Failing that, you can 'flag' the post for moderator attention (if and ***only*** if you feel the post isn't being seen).
3. The nuclear option is a Meta post if you feel this warrants a broader discussion. But don't whine about the closure; such discussions work better when posted in the context of seeking further clarification in a broader context. A meta post isn't generally a place I would *start.*

<sup>…in that order ↑</sup>

Good luck!